# Is it possible to be redirected to a specific page with that page's widget open?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to the flutter, and I have a question. When the user creates the account, I would like to redirect him to the configuration page with a certain Widget on the page already open. It's possible?

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
          return SettingsWidget();
}));
```

I'm using this code to direct the Configuration page, but the Widget that has the person inside would have to click on the button, but I wanted it to be already open.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question.... you can use a constructor parameter `SettingsWidget(myFlag)` and then test `myFlag` inside build method to know what to do

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to show a dialog as soon as the page opens! If that is your requirement you can do this:

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SchedulerBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => showDialog(context));
    
  }
```